# The captcha solution was not correct. Please try again

Tags: php, oauth-2.0, instagram, instagram-api

I'm trying to use login form that contains Oauth2 feature to login the user with instagram.
For this purpose I'm trying to **create new Client id** in instagram developer page but here are the problems I'm facing:

> The captcha solution was not correct. Please try again
>
> Submission error: please fill out all required fields.

although I 'v no captcha in the form of creating new client ID and I'v filled out all the fields.

Second thing I want to know:
Can I use localhost for **website URLS** and **the redirect URLS** as I'm using it(you can see in the attached image),if no then what is the alternative because I'v no website.
[image]

Comment: Not an actual programming problem, it seems. Try and open this form in a private browser window, to make sure it’s not any of your extensions blocking the captcha or something like that.

Comment: I'v asked about the URLS also, can I use 'localhost' as my website url in the form or I'v to put valid website url please confirm. @misorude

Comment: @mehmoodkhan — Don't ask multiple questions in one Stackoverflow question. It will get it closed as "Too broad"

Comment: well, the main programming related question is just , using 'localhost' is ok or not in the URLS? I'v mentioned the errors of captcha so that may be someone have faced such kind of problem and solved that.@Quentin

Comment: tried in new incognito window but same problem @misorude

Comment: You can use localhost URLs for everything that doesn’t require their system to make a request to yours. So all the login-related stuff that only redirects inside the user’s browser should work fine, anything that needs in incoming connection (such as webhooks) won’t. If you need that as well, look into using a service such as ngrok.

Comment: what do you recommend to use any special browser to solve the problem of captcha,it is important because this is from one of my cilent work?@misorude

Comment: @mehmoodkhan — If you depend on a website to provide a service, and it isn't working, then you should contact technical support for that website.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just ran into this issue also. Googled around and found the following solution. Install this chrome extension to disable Content-Security-Policy and disable it on the Instagram Developers page and you should see the Captcha.

https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/disable-content-security/ieelmcmcagommplceebfedjlakkhpden

Comment: Really helpful, thank you so much @sam it worked for me !

Comment: I was bothered mate ,Really it's good solution. Work for me :)